# How to show auto-frame-break counter in beamer frame subtitle?

Tags: beamer, titles

In beamer, I use a convention of inserting the section title as frame title and then providing a more specific title as subtitle. In this case, I think it makes more sense for me to show the "subframe" number after the frame subtitle instead of the frame title, which seems to be standard.

I have "borrowed" the following parts of beamerbaselocalstructure.sty

```
\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#2}{}{%
    \gdef\insertframetitle{{#2\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}%
  \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
  \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}%
}%
}
```

and

```
\mode
<all>
{
  \let\beamer@aftersubtitle=\relax
\newcommand<>\framesubtitle[1]{\only#2{\beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\gdef\insertframesubtitle{{#1}}\beamer@aftersubtitle}}}
}
```

and dirty-hacked it as follows into a beamer document:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#2}{}{%
    \gdef\insertframetitle{{#2}}%
  \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
  \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}%
}%
}
\mode
<all>
{
  \let\beamer@aftersubtitle=\relax
  \renewcommand<>\framesubtitle[1]{\only#2{\beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\gdef\insertframesubtitle{{#1\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}\beamer@aftersubtitle}}}
}
\makeatother
```

It *almost* works: in the first frame, it shows the subtitle as "Subtitle I", but in the second (auto-broken) frame, the subtitle becomes "Subtitle II II" where I wanted "Subtitle II". I cannot figure out which part of the code causes the repetition of "II"?

I know I should not be hacking around like this since beamer may have a proper interface to redefine the frame subtitle instead, but I simply don't know.

Comment: You should provide a MWE to allow others help you.

Comment: Voted unclear: no MWE after request.